# How to update solution to .NET Framework 4.8?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, .net-framework-version

I am using VS2019 and C# (win form) in a solution containing 390 projects using .NET Framework 4. Is there a way to upgrade all projects to .NET Framework 4.8 together or do I have to manually change all single project?

I started trying to manually change every single project but it's very long thanks a lot

Comment: Use Find&Replace on whole solution and replace old value with new one. Better option is to extract version into Directory.Build.props, even better would be to migrate to sdk-style project

Comment: It only sets the *minimum* version that the user needs to have installed on their machine.  And only the setting on the main .exe project dictates it.  Extremely small odds that you need to update one of the projects because you use a feature that only 4.8 has available.

Comment: If my opinion is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2019, there is no direct built-in feature to upgrade multiple projects to a new .NET Framework version in a single action. You will need to manually upgrade each project individually. However, you may try to create a PowerShell or command-line script to automate the task.

If possible, take your time with each project and build the solution frequently so that when there is an issue, it will be easy to isolate based on your previous changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Target Framework Migrator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PavelSamokha.TargetFrameworkMigrator). It currently supports up to Visual Studio 2019.

After opening the Target Framework Migrator, in the pop-up window, select the .NetFramework version you want to upgrade, select the project you want to upgrade, and finally click the Migrate button.